# firebase functions v1 traffic handling

Tags: node.js

I'd like to implement a logic that uses firebase functions to process 100 simultaneous HTTP requests for a process that takes 2-3 seconds per task.

Is there a way to directly control built instances of firebase functions, or check their status?

I tested it to do load balancing on its own by asynchronizing tasks or by calling firebase functions. If there are not enough instances, there is no log in the Google cloud, but the client receives an HTTP response of 500